# Proof of interior gradient estimate for Laplace's equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I have a question about the proof of the estimate
$$
|\nabla u(x_0)| \leq \frac{n}{R} \max_{\bar{B}_R(x_0)} |u|
$$
where $u$ is assumed to be harmonic.

Since $u_{x_i}$ is harmonic, by the mean value property and integration by parts,
$$
u_{x_i}(x_0) = \frac{r}{\omega_n R^n}\int_{B_R(x_0)} u_{x_i}(y) dy = \frac{n}{\omega_n R^n}\int_{\partial B_R(x_0)} u(y) \nu_i dS_y.
$$
Taking the absolute value, we obtain
$$
|u_{x_i}(x_0)| \leq \frac{n}{\omega_n R^n} \int_{\partial B_R(x_0)} |u(y)| dS_y \leq \frac{n}{R}\max_{\bar{B}_R(x_0)} |u|.
$$
I understand the preceding steps. What I don't understand is how this obviously proves the desired result. This is my attempt at obtaining the desired result:
\begin{align*}
|\nabla u(x_0)|^2 &= u_{x_1}^2(x_0) + \cdots + u_{x_n}^2(x_0) \\
&\leq \underbrace{\frac{n^2}{R^2}(\max_{\bar{B}_R(x_0)} |u|)^2 + \cdots + \frac{n^2}{R^2}(\max_{\bar{B}_R(x_0)} |u|)^2}_{\text{$n$ times}}\\
&=\frac{n^3}{R^2}(\max_{\bar{B}_R(x_0)} |u|)^2.
\end{align*}
Taking the square root,
$$
|\nabla u(x_0)| \leq \left(\frac{n^3}{R^2}(\max_{\bar{B}_R(x_0)} |u|)^2\right)^{1/2} = \frac{n^{3/2}}{R}\max_{\bar{B}_R(x_0)}.
$$

I'm not sure where my logic is wrong and I am aware this must be something simple...

Comment: If you want to merge your posts under this account https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3779224/t-derivative-of-kirchhoffs-solution/3779229#comment7781643_3779229 (if it is indeed you) then you can flag any post of yours for a moderator to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line
$$u_{x_i}(x_0) =\frac{n}{\omega_n R^n}\int_{\partial B_R(x_0)} u(y) \nu_i \,dS_y$$
would be the components of the equation
$$\nabla u(x_0) = \frac{n}{\omega_n R^n}\int_{\partial B_R(x_0)} u(y) \nu\, dS_y$$
And now you do the approximation at this level:
\begin{align}|\nabla u(x_0)| 
&= \frac{n}{\omega_n R^n}\left|\int_{\partial B_R(x_0)} u(y) \nu\, dS_y\right| 
\\
&\le \frac{n}{\omega_n R^n}\int_{\partial B_R(x_0)} |u(y) \nu|\, dS_y \\
&=\frac{n}{\omega_n R^n}\int_{\partial B_R(x_0)} |u(y) |\, dS_y \\
&\le \frac{n}{R}\|u\|_{L^\infty(\overline{B_R(x_0)})}. \end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Calvin Khor Hello Calvin, I have one question. Is $n/R$ the best the coefficient? It seems that we lose nothing in the above estimation, so I actually want to ask that does there exists some harmonic function $u$, such that $\nabla u(x_0)=n/r\|u\|_{L^\infty}$? Thanks!

Comment: @Frankie sorry, I don’t know! Could ask a new question